# Chrome extensions: Sending a request to remote API when user is visiting specific pages

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm not exactly sure what Chrome APIs to use and how to use them in order to:

1. Read Page content on specific domain names (Ex. only trigger when URL contains google.com)
2. Send requests to a remote server and get data back

The Chrome Extensions Dev page is confusing and feels incomplete, would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: 1) Use a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), 2) Use `fetch` in the background script + [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should learn [the basic of manifest file](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/getstarted/) of a Chrome Extension.
Then to write an extension to be able to achieve your requirements, you could:

*Read Page content on specific domain names (Ex. only trigger when URL contains google.com)*

With this, you could use [Content Script](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/):

1. Write a JS script (or CSS also work)
2. Update content script config in manifest file to load the JS script when accessing on specific domain names

*Send requests to a remote server and get data back*

You have to:

1. Update [permissions section](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/permission_warnings/) inside manifest file to allow access into the remote server, for example:

```
{
    ...
    permissions: [
        "*://yourremoteserver.com/*" // Read the doc for more detail how to request permission to call request into a server
    ]
    ...
}
```

2. Only background script allows you to send API request into the remote server, so if you want to do something for example: Read Page content on specific domain names and then send the data from that page into your remote server, you have to create a [messaging flow](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/messaging/) to send message from Content Script into Background Script and then from there you could use fetch API to send requests into your remote server.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer! It really helped a lot.